# Web Service call how to wait for N seconds and abort

Tags: web-services, c#-3.0

We've an SLA that the third party RESTfull web service must return the response within 5 seconds. Otherwise we need to abort the service call and do other part of business logics.

Could some one please help me with how we can achieve about using C#.Net.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WCF to call the external webservice then just configure the sendTimeout value in client endpoint's binding configuration to be 5 sec. Then if the client proxy object doesn't get a reply from the external service a TImeoutException will be thrown and you can handle that and continue. An example binding configuration is shown below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="myExternalBindingConfig"
               openTimeout="00:01:00"
               closeTimeout="00:01:00"
               sendTimeout="00:05:00"
               receiveTimeout="00:01:00">
       </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What are you using to make the web service call, WebClient ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface my answer by offering up front the "standard disclaimer" that part of the practice I'm going to offer here is considered *bad*, because of possible issues dealing with unmanaged code. With that said, here is an answer:

```
void InitializeWebServiceCall(){

    Thread webServiceCallThread = new Thread(ExecuteWebService);
    webServiceCallThread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(5000); // make the current thread wait 5 seconds
    if (webServiceCallThread.IsAlive()){
      webServiceCallThread.Abort(); // warning for deprecated/bad practice call!!
    }
}

static void ExecuteWebService(){

    // the details of this are left to the consumer of the method
    int x = WebServiceProxy.CallWebServiceMethodOfInterest();
    // do something fascinating with the result

}
```

Calling Thread.Abort() is deprecated since .NET 2.0, and is generally considered a bad programming practice due primarily to the potential for adverse interactions with unmanaged code. The risks associated with using the code are, of course, for you to assess.